# How to read a html map created and saved with folium back into folium as a map object to do some changes?

Tags: html, dictionary, folium

Im working with folium maps and saving them as html files. Later I would like to do some changes to existing maps.

##### Creating and saving the map

map = folium.Map(location=[45.3, 8.6], tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start=10)

target_path = "D:/XXXX/XXXX/"

map.save(target_path + 'Map.html')

##### Open again with folium to do changes??

Is there a way to open or load "Map.html" again into folium as a folium map object?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

once your map is created you can not edit it i guess. You can add "macros" with js code so your map could behave the way you want